# About url rewrite with query string and form action get

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please help to remove additional query string

I use this code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^ip/(.*)$ /iplookup.php?lookup_ip=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works, but when try to lookup additional ip address in form,
 it shows something like this in address bar :

```
"/ip/?lookup_ip=66.249.66.2"
```

My form is

```
<form action="/ip/" method="get">
<input type="text" value="{$address}" name="lookup_ip" id="lookup_ip">
<input type="submit" value="IP Lookup"/>
</form>
```

Is it possible to hide "?lookup_ip=" now

I want to show /ip/66.249.66.2

I think my problem is in form?

Comment: you will have to change the method of form to post. Just a suggestion, give it a try

Comment: changed to post and noting works :( not display IP in url too can't look additional ip too (redirects to same) example of my php code `if ($_GET['lookup_ip']) {
        $query = gethostbyname($_GET['lookup_ip']);
}else{
        $query = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}`

Comment: i guess, you are using wrong function. gethostbyname is used to get ip-address from hostname. checkout this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php

Comment: yes, because i want to find domain name ip too

Answer (score 5):

When you submit a GET request form the link is changed to include the parameter and the value as `param=value`. You cannot change that by default.

You could use javascript to do it for you.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function SubmitForm() {
  var val = document.getElementById('lookup_ip').value;

  //check val for length / valid IP here

  window.location.href='/ip/' + val;
  return false;
}
</script>

<form action="/ip/" method="get" onsubmit='return SubmitForm()'>
<input type="text" value="{$address}" name="lookup_ip" id="lookup_ip">
<input type="submit" value="IP Lookup"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, you may have saved be a lot of trial and error!